# Prefuse Library: How to add <link> to a node built using prefuse library?

Tags: java, prefuse, flashbuilder4

I am new to Prefuse library and Java.
I did install eclipse,flash builder plugin for eclipse and compiled the code. I want to make some modifications to the existing sample. TreeView.java

In this sample we add only TEXT as a NODE. Can I add a link to web page so that when users click on a node, will direct to a web page.

Kindly let me know, If you can help me on this ?

Regards,

vismaran.

Answer (score 0):

I've never done this before, but I think it can be done via controls and actions.

Three steps:

1. Define an action/activity for opening external webpages; I would assume this class would extend the prefuse Activity class
2. Add your new activity to an action list, and assign it a name
3. Add a new FocusControl object to your visualization, and create it with the activity attached, so that when a vis element is in focus, this activity is trigger.

I hope this helps.